# Show that $f$ is increasing when $\alpha=0$ and decreasing when $\alpha=1$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $$f(x)=(x+\alpha)\log\left(1+ {1 \over x}\right)$$ 
Show that $f$ is increasing when $\alpha=0$ and decreasing when $\alpha=1$  on $[1,\infty)$

The derivative is:
$$f'(x)=\log\left(1+{1 \over x}\right) - {{x+\alpha} \over x(x+1)}$$

for $\alpha=0$:
$f'(x)=\log(1 + {1 \over x}) - {1 \over x+1}$

for $\alpha=1$:
$f'(x)=\log(1 + {1 \over x}) - x$

Now, I thought using Taylor Expansion in order to prove it, but is it necessary? Is there a simple way showing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea: define

$$g(x):=\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)-\frac1{x+1}\implies g'(x)=-\frac1{x(x+1)}+\frac1{(x+1)^2}=$$

$$\frac1{x+1}\left(\frac1{x+1}-\frac1x\right)=-\frac1{x(x+1)^2}< 0\;\;\forall\,x\in[1,\infty)$$

and thus $\;f\;$ is monotone descending, and:

$$g(1)=\log2-\frac12>0\;,\;\;\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\log 1-0=0$$

Thus, $\;g\;$ is always positive (this is not the shortest way but, perhaps, one of the most basic ones)

Try now to do something similar with the other case.

Answer (score 3):

We can write the logarithm as an integral,

$$\log \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right) = \log (x+1) - \log x = \int_x^{x+1} \frac{dt}{t}.$$

That integral is easily recognised as smaller than $\dfrac{1}{x}$ and larger than $\dfrac{1}{x+1}$.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm a Calculus 1 student. Using integrals not allowed.

Comment: Can you use the mean value theorem, $$f(y) - f(x) = f'(\xi)\cdot (y-x)$$ for a $\xi \in (x,y)$?

Comment: Yes. I am allowed to use MVT